# Pass selector from UIViewController to UIView

Tags: ios, swift

I've created a custom class that inherits from UIView, `BlueView`.
I have a method in my UIViewController that I want to have called when `BlueView` is tapped by the user. However, my program crashes whenever I tap the `BlueView` with this exception:

```
2019-09-15 23:06:14.960704-0400 DoubleViewApp[2418:70709] -[DoubleViewApp.BlueView handleBlueTapWithSender:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7f820cd06790
```

UIView:

```
import UIKit

class BlueView: UIView {

  override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
    createSubview()
  }

  required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    createSubview()
  }

  func createSubview() {
    print("createSubview from BlueView")
    backgroundColor = .blue

    let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handleTap(sender:)))
    addGestureRecognizer(tap)
  }

  func setTapGesture(action: Selector?) {
    let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: action)
    addGestureRecognizer(tap)
  }

  @objc func handleTap(sender: UITapGestureRecognizer? = nil) {
    print("NO! DO NOT TAP THE BLUE SQUARE.")

  }

}
```

ViewController:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {


  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    print("Hello World")
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    let bview = BlueView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 300, height: 300))
    let rview = RedView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 300, width: 300, height: 300))
    view.addSubview(bview)
    view.addSubview(rview)

    bview.setTapGesture(action: #selector(handleBlueTap(sender:)))
  }


  @objc func handleBlueTap(sender: UITapGestureRecognizer? = nil) {
    print("This is a funny message.")
    //Todo: Present new ViewController
  }
}
```

Comment: BlueView doesn't have "handleBlueTap".

Comment: Right, I figured that was the issue. I've worked around it by creating the UITapGestureRecognizer in the UIViewContainer and passing it to BlueView with setTapGesture. Is there a more standard way? Would letting the BlueView know of the UIViewController it's contained in be a better method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You also have to set the correct *target* for the selector. At the moment, you are setting the target as the `BlueView` instance, but you want it to be the view controller.

```swift
class BlueView: UIView {

    ...

    func setTapGesture(target: Any?, action: Selector?) {
        addGestureRecognizer(UITapGestureRecognizer(target: target, action: action))
    }

    ...

}
```

& then you can use:

```swift
bview.setTapGesture(target: self, action: #selector(handleBlueTap(sender:)))
```